# Fail to get all usernames from table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to retrieve all usernames listed in my members table, list them in a page and link them to their user profile. This is how I retrieve the usernames of the members table:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT username FROM members");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$username = $row['username'];
```

In order to link them, I'll be using the following:

```
<?php 
foreach ($result as $row) {
?>
    <a href="#"><?php echo $username ?></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

The problem is that it's only showing 1 username, 5 times. So I get like:

username1
username1
username1
username1
username1

rather than

username1
username2
username3
username4
username5

What am I doing wrong? (sorry, recently started learning PHP/MYSQL so I'm quite new to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're only getting the first result. Try:

```
$users = array();
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT username FROM members");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $users[] = $row['username']; 
}

<?php 
foreach ($users as $user): ?>

<a href="#"><?php echo $user; ?></a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Try mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_array and see if that works.

Comment: Glad to help - Yeah, the MySqli fetch array can be used like this, but it's much easier to use the mysqli_fetch_assoc. the array can be used like this: $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC); - but to me, too verbose IMHO. Have fun!

Comment: @chas688 Thanks again. One quick question though > I've created a profile page and I'd like to get several columns from the same table. I then need to put it into a variable like: $username = $row['username'];, $name = $row['name'];, and so on. Would I do the same as you just explained/posted or could I use a much simpler method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT username FROM members");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

<?php 
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $username = $row['username']; 
?>
    <a href="#"><?php echo $username ?></a>
<?php
}
?>
```

You need to get the user name for each item in the row.

Comment: `$result` is a `mysqli::result` resource object, not an array of results.  A `while` loop is needed to fetch multiple rows.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski since php 5.4, mysqli_result is Traversable.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller woah  I hadn't seen that. That's really surprising and potentially confusing but also really welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT username FROM members");
 $count=0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

 array[$count]['Rkey'] = $count;
 $array[$count]['username']= $row['username'];
 $count++;

}

 mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
```

to print the values

$res_count= count($array);

```
for ($x=0;$x<$res_count;$x++)
{
  echo $array[$x]['username'];
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but thats not what I'm looking for. I should be able to print it anywhere I want